Google Tag Manager (GTM) Preview is broken. Cannot read properties of null (reading 'replace')
Preview mode of Google Tag Manager (GTM) doesn't see opened pages.
GTM and Google Analytics stop working for these pages.
The Summary block in https://tagassistant.google.com/ is empty or lists events not from all pages of my site.

I see the following JavaScript error in browser's DevTools
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'replace')

that is caused by document.referrer equal null on my web pages.

Workaround
Open browser's DevTools > Console, and find all failing places with this error.
Currently there are two.

Click the firs blue row in each and you'll see the failing code.

Set a breakpoint on it and edit this breakpoint from the context menu to add a condition.
Use this code as a condition
a != null ? false : (a = '')


See that the breakpoint has the condition now.

The workaround is done. Preview mode of GTM now will be working right.
Warning
The code with the issue is compressed and in the future the name of a function parameter could be changed to something else. Replace the a correspondingly.
Reason
Probably you web pages have document.referrer equal null.
This could be caused by 302 HTTP redirects which could be fired by some tricky authentication or something else on your site.
You could use Redirect Path Chrome extension to see it.
There's the same code bug in both GTM's Tag Assistant and Tag Assistant Companion extension of Google Chrome.
Their code uses document.referrer as mentioned below.
d = {
    href: e,
    title: f,
    referrer: q(d.document.referrer),
    readyState: d.document.readyState
};

that leads to invocation of null.replace(...) of a string in the code like this
​function q(a) {
    return a.replace(/([\?&])gtm_debug=x&/, "$1").replace(/[\?&]gtm_debug=x($|#)/, "$1")
}

I hope they fix it fast. I reported it in the Tag Manager Help Community
